# Getting location of multiple people

Tags: android

My application can locate only 1 person at a time but what if i want my app to locate multiple people at a time.. 
I tried to do this by using for loop but its not working ..  I have an edit Text in my app and a button named as Add , write any number on edit text and click Add , a number will be added to list then i have a button named as Locate , by clicking that locate button, i want my app to locate those persons that are added to certain list . Can anyone tell me how to do this ?
Here is My Code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fl_number_provider);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnflAddNum);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.flPhoneNumber);
        strNumber = number.getText().toString();

        if (strNumber == "")
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Required Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
        contacts.add(strNumber);
        //x++;
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listview.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                textView.setText(contacts.get(position));

                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return contacts.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return contacts.size();
            }
        });


            number.setText("");
            }

        }
        });



    //number = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.flPhoneNumber);
    //listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    LocationHead = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.flLastKnownLocationHead);
    LastLocation = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.flLastLocation);
    getLocation = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnflgetLocation);

    getLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //String num = number.getText().toString();
            //int x = contacts.size();
            try{
            if(contacts == null)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{

            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x+" - check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for(int i = 0; i <= contacts.size(); i++)
            {
            //String x = contacts.get(i).toString();
                    sendMsg(contacts.get(i), contacts.size()+ "message family location");

            //LocationHead.setText(contacts.get(i).toString());
            //LastLocation.setText("waiting....");
            }
            }
            }catch(Exception e){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString()+ "Field Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first, I am a chinese, so please forgive my poor english....

Your code is not good.

First, you put listView.setAdapter in btnAdd.setOnClickListener, so, every btnAdd clicked, listView setAdapter once.

The other problem is **for(int i = 0; i <= contacts.size(); i++)**, it will throw a IndexOutOfBound Exception. It is a fatal error, and when you click getLocation button, application will be crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (contacts.size > 0)
  for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
     ...
```